# Eye dropper color working wrong

Tags: texture-painting, color

For some reason when I select a new color, for some reason the previous one is displayed instead, but it is still marked on the color palette [image]
(on the picture I selectected dark pink one)

So to paint with correct color I need to click on it on the palette, so what can be fixed in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I found out solution
When I press hotkey (mine is X) I also click with a stilys (or LMB) - it's not needed.Just press a hotkey